# Mock constant values in with mockk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

We currently have an object that consists of constant values only.

```
object Constants {
    const val VERSION = V1
}
```

However, these constants' values may be altered in the future. Thus I want to ensure that a test breaks if certain conditions are not met by the `VERSION` value. We use Mockk for mocking so I tried to mock the `Constants` object according to the [docs](https://mockk.io/) like this

```
mockkObject(Constants)
every { Constants.VERSION } returns -1
assertThat(Constants.VERSION).isEqualTo(-1)
```

Unfortunately this does not compile with the following error: `io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.`

Is there a way to mock the constant value? Or should I provide getter methods for the constants and mock these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants in kotlin [don't have getters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants) which is the reason behind your exception: `io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block`. There is no function which can be mocked to retrieve the value.

I would suggest you rethink your goal of testing constants (which is not a typical test case), or to make a workaround. Workarounds could be:

- Create a getter for each constant you want to mock
- Put `Constants` inside an other class, which would return `Constants` object and you could test every field (with [assertJ fieldByField](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field))
- Put const values inside a text or properties file which can be tested

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `Whitebox` from [PowerMockMockito](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.6.4/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html); yes, you can use `Whitebox` together with MockK. The advantage of `Whitebox` is that you have the freedom of setting a constant to any value you'd like without the hassle of creating wrapper classes which are useless except for unit tests.

Example:

```
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox

Whitebox.setInternalState(Constants::class.java, (Constants::VERSION).name, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace constants with enum class and then mock them with MockObject. For example:

```
class MyClass {

enum class MyConstants( val param: String ) {
VERSION( "V1" ),
TEMP_FOLDER_PATH( "usr/temp/");
   }

 //to use in code:
 var tempFolder : String = MyConstants.TEMP_FOLDER_PATH.param
}
```

To mock it later in unit tests:

```
 mockObject( MyClass.MyConstants.TEMP_FOLDER_PATH )
 every { MyClass.MyConstants.TEMP_FOLDER_PATH.param } returns "whatever is needed"
```